# Is it possible to run Vowpal Wabbit daemon with file socket instead of using a port?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Official VW documentation has an example of how to run Vowpal Wabbit in daemon mode.
https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Daemon-example
But it seems that VW always binds a particular port to the daemon (by default it is port 26542).

It is possible to use file socket instead of a TCP socket for Vowpal Wabbit daemon mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now vowpalwabbit explicitly uses TCP sockets in deamon mode so the only thing you can define is the port you wish to use via `--port`.

PS: I'm a maintainer for this project and we would be more than happy to accept a patch with this if you need it, as we currently don't have plans to support this feature. Here is the related TCP code: https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/vowpalwabbit/parser.cc#L208